# Issue with rendering a square grid using opengl

Tags: c, opengl, glfw, glad

I'm trying to render a 2d grid using opengl. My code is as follows

Shaders

```
const char *vertex_shader_source = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
    "uniform mat4 projection;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = projection * vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
    "}\0";
const char *fragment_shader_source = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
    "uniform vec3 color;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\n\0";
```

Drawing:

```
void
square_draw(vec2 tl, vec2 br, vec3 color) {
    glUseProgram(shader_program);
    mat4 projection;
    glm_ortho(0.0f, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, projection);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, (const float *)&projection[0][0]);
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "color"), color[0], color[1], color[2]);

    const float vertices[] = {
        br[0], tl[1], 0.0, // top right
        br[0], br[1], 0.0, // bottom right
        tl[0], br[1], 0.0, // bottom left
        tl[0], tl[1], 0.0  // top left
    };

    const float indices[] = {
        0, 1, 3,
        1, 2, 3
    };

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```

Main:

```
int main() {
    init();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        for (int y = 0; y < MAP_Y; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < MAP_X; x++) {
                vec3 color = {0, 0, 0};
                if (map[y * MAP_X + x] == 1) {
                    glm_vec3_copy((vec3){1, 1, 1}, color);
                }

                const int xo = x * MAP_S;
                const int yo = y * MAP_S;
                square_draw(
                    (vec2){ xo + 1, yo + 1 },
                    (vec2){ MAP_S + xo - 1, MAP_S + yo -1 },
                color);
            }
        }
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

However nomatter what i try it always renders like this:
[image: render error]

My guess is an error within the `square_draw` function but the vertices contain the correct points but they dont seem to be setting correctly?

I'm not sure what exactly i am doing wrong

Comment: The type of the indices must be integral, but not `float`. So `const unsigned int indices[]` instead of `const float indices[]`